# Is having a large amount of constant data in code a bad practice?

Tags: c++, performance, constants

In my application I want to add large amounts of const strings, like stored procedures and functions to be installed from code.

Is that a bad practice or a performance issue?

**EDIT**

---

My question is so clear

```
const TCHAR* str = _T("SO SO LONG STRING .......................");//this string may exceeds 20,000 leter also I'll have many variables like this one containing big and huge strings
```

the question is "is there any problem with that?? the application size will increase and it's load time and so on" is it clear????

Comment: What is large-data to you?  How many characters?

Comment: It certainly not a performance issue. Whether is bad practise depends. Ask yourself this question, 'Am I likely to want to change the strings without rebuilding the program?' If the answer is yes then you should store the strings in a separate file and read the file in your program. That way you can change the strings without rebuilding the program.

Comment: if the program is very large..meaningful constants are very useful in future..like documentation.

Comment: @john : The string is different and varying from version to another in each build, for example in this version we are updating some tables adding new ones....

Comment: @Blam: its varying from small (about 500) to large(about 30,000)

Answer (score 2):

One important issue when dealing with constants defined in code is the need to recompile whenever any of these constants changes. When your constants represent strings that may need to be updated in production, such as the code of your stored procedures or user-defined functions that you load into the database at start-up, using a file that you ship with your product and store at a predefined location may provide a more flexible alternative.

As far as the performance goes, accessing string constants defined in code is faster than reading them from an external location.

Comment: Really we test on our debug solution tell we reach the end of this version, any reported bugs will be solved in the next version build, and those strings are for the the use of first work of the application after the installation, also at creating a new database, now we depend on another solution we use hard-disk SQL files for the installation and for the upgrade also we add the names of tables and stored procs to the C++ code, I wanted to make it in a central place ,now the developer will have to change in 3 sql files and also in the C++, I wanted to make it simple...

Comment: @Ahmedsafan Having 3 copies of the same code is a worthy issue to address.  Whether or not it is best solved by having the code as a constant in a compiled program or an external data file is a different question.

Comment: @brianbeuning: not three copies of the code, three places int C++ files we add the names, in the 1st SQL file we add the body, in install sql file and in upgrade sql file we add the name of the sql file

Comment: @Ahmedsafan What you said makes sense: as long as there's no duplication of the info, you're OK. The solution where the schema is embedded in SQL files that you ship separately from the main executable the way you do in the upcoming version is precisely the solution I was talking about in my answer.